# Title bar bug in .Net Maui Application?

Tags: c#, android, .net, mobile, maui

I am currently building a mobile application using Maui. The navigation of this application utilises the app shell, namely the navbar featured at the bottom of the screen.

As an addition to this, the top navigation area features the title of the current page as standard, but also additional icons to the right hand side such as settings, notifications etc.

To accomplish this, I have had to build a custom 'TitleView'. Right now I have stripped it down to simplicity, working with a simple image for the Icon and a label for the TitleView. The only dynamic property here is the fact the text of this label is updated by specific page's backend using an x:Name reference. It is worth noting, that I'm having the same issue even when using a static label that isn't dynamically changed.

Everything seems to work perfectly, but I'm having a strange bug where the 'visibility' of this custom TitleView seems to toggle on and off with each navigation of the navbar. This isn't page specific, it happens each time you navigate to a different page regardless of what that page is.

I'll try and illustrate this below with different navigation steps:
Page 1 (Visible) -> Page 2 (Hidden) -> Page 3 (Visible).
Page 1 (Visible) -> Page 3 (Hidden) -> Page 2 (Visible) -> Page 1 (Hidden)

So even on pages that the TitleView were hidden on, if I navigate twice from that page before navigating back, it's visible again and visa versa.

I have scoured the internet and cannot seem to find anything referencing this issue, nor do any of the AI's available help to diagnose it whatsoever. There are no errors flagging and I can't seem to see any form of property change.

Interestingly, if I remove this custom TitleView and use the default title, it works fine. I've also tried stripping this down to it's most simplistic form so that it only contains the title label without the grid or stack layouts and with no custom fonts or stylings, it has the same effect.

Could this be a conflict between using the top navigation area and the bottom Navbar? I'm not using the flyout menu or anything like that, as I know using a flyout and a Navbar can have undesired results.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Here is my XAML markup from the AppShell:

```
<!-- Custom title view with icon in the top right corner -->
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="TitleLabel" Text="Title Text" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultBold}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Column="1">
            <Image Source="mob_icon_settings_w.png" WidthRequest="35" HeightRequest="35" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>


<!-- Add a TabBar to display ShellContent on the bottom of the page -->
<TabBar>
    <!-- Add ShellContent for each page to be displayed at the bottom -->
    <ShellContent
        Title="Dashboard"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DashboardPage}"
        Icon="dashboard.png"
        Route="dashboard" />

    <ShellContent
        Title="Transactions"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:TransactionsPage}"
        Route="TransactionsPage" />

    <ShellContent
        Title="Get Paid!"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:QuickPayPage}"
        Route="QuickPayPage" />

    <ShellContent
        Title="User Management"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:UserManagementPage}"
        Route="UserManagementPage" />
</TabBar>
```

Comment: Could be related to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16015, https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15875 and/or https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13347

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at these now.